# Copy, paste and cut operations on Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-selectors

**Hi All,**

I'm trying put some features to textarea like copy, cut and paste buttons but even I tried many times I couldn't get only part of text inside of textarea. it comes all content.

My Code below:

```
function copy() {
    var VAL = $("#selection").select();
    var DTA = $(this).text();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.execCommand("delete");
}
```

My Work below:

https://jsfiddle.net/dcn7pgkn/

How it would be possible that one user may copy, paste and cut operations inside of textarea?

**Thanks**

Comment: Code does not work for me at all, neither in IE11 or Chrome, " 'copy' is undefined"

Answer (score 1):

**First** You have to add brackets to your function in HTML code

```
<button onclick="copy()">Copy selected text</button>
```

**Second** You have to configure your jsfiddle right, you have to specify that you are using **JQuery** and Load Type should be **No wrap - in <head>**

[image]

Your code is currently copying textarea text and clearing the textarea, for copying I don't see that this line is needed:

```
var DTA = $(this).text();
```

copying shouldn't clear textarea, this line appropriate for cut action.